# Пара вопросов по async / await

Tags: c#, многопоточность

Всем привет, возникла сложность в понимании работы этих слов. Вот есть код:

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Threading;
class a
{
    public int x;
    public Task Sum()
    {
        Task<int> t = Task<int>.Factory.StartNew(i => { Thread.Sleep(5000); return (int)i; }, 999);
        x = t.Result;
        return t;
    }
    public async Task Demo()
    {
        await Sum();
    }
}
class b
{
    static void Main()
    {
        a A = new a();
        Console.WriteLine(A.x);
        A.Demo();
        Console.WriteLine(A.x);
    }
}
```

1. Почему при запуске этого кода ожидается выполнение метода Demo(), ведь он же имеет `await Sum()`, который должен сообщить компилятору, что он временно занят и отдать управление методу `Main`, который должен завершиться не дождавшись окончания метода `Demo` ? Однако так и происходит если удалить в методе `Sum` строку `x = t.Result`. Почему так происходит ?
2. Правильно ли я понимаю, что методы `Main`, `Demo`, `Sum`  - запускаются в одном и том же потоке, или Sum в силу наличия ключевого слова await запускается в отдельном потоке ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Давайте я поясню, что происходит.

1. Главный поток начинает выполнение функции `Main`. Конструируется объект `A`, у него начальные значения полей обнуляются, так что `A.x` равно нулю. Это значение выводится на консоль.
2. Вызывается метод `A.Demo()`. Поскольку это `async`-метод, то из этого метода внутренним образом конструируется `Task`, который и возвращается. Конкретно происходит следующее.
3. Метод `A.Demo()` начинает выполняться синхронно в том же потоке до первого `await`. Этот `await` находится в первой строке: `await Sum()`. Это значит, что сначала вычислится аргумент `await` (`Sum()`).
4. Начинает выполняться метод `Sum()`. Это обыкновенный метод, который создаёт `Task` и возвращает его. рассмотрим, как он выполняется.
5. При помощи `Task<int>.Factory.StartNew` создаётся новый `Task`, который немедленно начинает выполняться на thread pool'е (из-за `StartNew`), то есть в другом потоке. Параллельно этому продолжается выполнение метода `Sum()` в главном потоке.
6. Следующая строчка `x = t.Result;` обращается к результату `Task`'а, запущенного на thread pool'е. Это **блокирующий** вызов, который приостанавливает выполнение главного потока до тех пор, пока `t` не завершится.
7. Строчка `return t;` возвращает уже завершённый `Task`. Мы возвращаемся в функцию `Demo()`.
8. В функции `Demo()` вычислился аргумент для `await`, и теперь выполняется сам `await`. `await` для начала проверяет, не завершился ли `Task` к текущему моменту. Поскольку это так и есть, `await` считает себя отработавшим. Управление переходит к следующему оператору — то есть, функция `Demo()` на этом заканчивается.
9. Теперь функция `Demo()` неявным образом создаёт `Task`, чтобы вернуть его (ведь возвращаемый тип — `Task`). Поскольку функция отработала **до конца**, этот `Task` создаётся уже завершённым.
10. Наконец, в функцию `Main()` возвращается уже завершённый `Task`. Хотя этот `Task` игнорируется, он уже отработал, так что проблем с этим нет.
11. Выполняется вывод `A.x` на консоль. Программа завершается.

Таким образом, игнорирование `Task`'а, возвращённого методом `Demo()`, не привело к проблемам лишь потому, что этот `Task` был уже завершён. Если бы это было не так, завершение программы по выходу из `Main` возможно не дало бы ему завершиться.

Обратите внимание, что если бы не обращение `t.Result`, то из `Sum()` вернулся бы *незавершённый* `Task`. В этом случае `await` в `Demo()` получил бы незавершённый `Task`, и **прервал** выполнение кода функции `Demo()` и вернул другой незавершённый `Task` в `Main`. В этом случае игнорирование результата вызова `Demo` могла бы привести к «потере» незавершённого `Task`'а из-за окончания программы.

Comment: Ох, уважаемый, чтобы я без вас делал ! Тогда, если я правильно понял, то все-таки Main, Demo, Sum, работают в одном и том же потоке (что определяется если в начале каждого из этих методов вставить `Console.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId)`), однако дальше от потока отскакивает Factory.StartNew в отдельный поток, а поток Sum продолжает идти дальше, и натыкается на блокирующий код, который ожидает результат. И получается что Main поток заблокирован

Comment: @PolyakovSergey: Да, именно так и есть. Большая часть кода выполняется в главном потоке.

Answer (score 2):

1. Ну вообще если вы запрашиваете Result у Task, то вполне естественно, что тем самым дожидаетесь выполнения асинхронной операции чтобы этот самый Result получить. О чем и говорит msdn:

> Метод доступа get для этого свойства гарантирует, что асинхронная операция завершена перед возвратом. Когда результат вычисления становится доступным, он сохраняется и будет возвращаться немедленно при последующих вызовах Result.
>   Однако стоит отметить, что вовсе не обязательно, что дополнительный поток вообще будет использован.

так что читайте документацию лучше.

2. Абстракция async/await позволяет вам забыть об этих самых потоках, запуск потоков в данном случае - уже внутреннее дело CLR. Но вообще Main и Demo  разумеется, запускаются в одном потоке. Однако Demo выполняется в этом потоке до тех пор, пока выполнение не дойдет до инструкции await. Далее уже для для await-кода обычно выделяется поток из пула, который занимается выполнением "тяжелого" кода, а основной поток возвращает Task.

Кстати засовывать **Task< int>** в Task явно дурная идея

Comment: Просто в чем у меня еще неразбериха вышла, что я во все эти методы Main, Demo, Sum вставил такой код в самом начале `Console.WriteLine(Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId);` и везде в них был один и тот же ИД, но когда я добавил этот код в `Task<int>.Factory.StartNew` то ИД был уже другой

Comment: @polyakov_s это лишь говорит о том, что CLR хорошо знает, когда выделение потока из пула не имеет смысла